# how to make a separate menu on the page?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

please tell me how to django-cms is a separate menu page

for example, there is the main menu:

```
-Home 
-blog 
-Contact 
-Map
```

I need that when the user is on the page "blog" in the left column there are additional menu consisting of:

```
-blog1 
-blog2 
-blog3
```

but on the other pages of the menu was not.

I made 2 templates: one column and two-column. appointed two-column page template for "blog." the problem is that I do not understand how to bind an additional menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I recommend you to check [CMS docs: Navigation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/navigation.html)

There you can read about useful template tags to generate menus, the 2 I allways use are:

1. `{% show_menu %}`
2. `{% show_menu_below_id 'CMS_PAGE_ID'%}`

***(The CMS pages have to be Published and checked for Navigation or they won't appear in the menu)***

Both tags auto-generates a menu using a template, you can customize this template if you create a file in `your_project/templates/menu/menu.html` or put the template in any other place and add it to the template tag like `{% show_menu 100 100 100 100 'yourpath/template_name.html' %}`.

The biggest difference between this 2 templatetags is that the first one shows the navigation of the actual page (parents or children depending on some variables I explain later) and the second one autogenerates the menu of a page using the unique ID of the page (You should write this unique ID in the advanced options when editing/creating a CMS page)

So in your project, to do the thing you're trying to achieve you could use:

```
{% show_menu 0 2 100 100 %}
```

You should check the documentation I refer at the beginning to understand best this 4 numbers but the important here are the first and the second.

- The first number refers to the *startlevel* (the lowest level you want to show)
- The second number referst to the *endlevel* (the highest level you want to show)

So if you do `{% show_menu 0 2 100 100 %}` you will show the cms pages from level 0 to 2, this could be your main menu.

This is the best way to add a menu to your template, if you want to add another menu you could repeat the template tag and play with the numbers to fit your needs